# How to create cutom link for page

Tags: pages, url-rewriting, urls

I am newbie in WordPress, and my question may be duplicated, but I cant get this, help please. I have page with this URL: `example.com/?page_id=49`, but I want to make it as `example.com/test_page`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Settings -> Permalinks` to Post Name.

Go to your page and edit the Permalink field below the title field.

Comment: It happens. Glad I could help :)